# How to send data back to MainActivity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have MainActivity and I´m using startActivityForResult in it to open another activity in which I´m working with some data in list. I can edit these data and delete too. After clicking on back button of my phone I want to send this edited list back to main activity.
Where should I create that intent with that new list?Is there any method which I can override for that back button pressed?

Comment: yes. Override onBackPressed() on your second activity and start an intent that goes to the main activity with extras.

Comment: Yeah that is what i was looking for. I probably missed that when i was searching in override methods! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `onBackPressed` and pass the data back to the original `Activity`. But in order to pass it like this, the list must implement `Parcelable`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putParcelableArrayList("someKey", listThatImplementsParcelable);
    intent.putExtras(data);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your MainActivity call the AnotherActivity using startActivityForResult() method:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

If you need, in your AnotherActivity set the data which you want to return back to MainActivity.

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("mData", object);
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

In MainActivity you have to Override/Implement the onActivityResult() method in this way:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("mData");
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // do something if there is no result
        }
    }
}
```

**See more:**

- [How To Manage startActivityForResult On Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android)
- [Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)